# Cannot execute unittests in python after docker run

Tags: python, docker, unit-testing

I rest api in python using fastApi and wrote couple of unittests for this.
When I run the tests locally in my VENV using **python3 -m unittest**, then everything works fine.

If use docker, where i do run **RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt** and then try to run **python3 -m unittest** I get a message *"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'"*.

I see that the problem is probably, that in the first case i run it inside the virtual environment but in the later (docker) case i do not. The funny thing though is, that the application itself (a little rest service based on fast api) does run.

How to overcome this problem?

Here is my docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

COPY src /app/src

COPY tests /app/tests

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


CMD ["hypercorn", "someScript:app", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--reload"]
```

Here is my requirements.txt

```
fastapi==0.65.2
h11==0.12.0
h2==4.0.0
hpack==4.0.0
Hypercorn==0.11.2
hyperframe==6.0.1
priority==1.3.0
pydantic==1.8.2
starlette==0.14.2
toml==0.10.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
wsproto==1.0.0
```

Comment: Show us your `Dockerfile` and your `requirements.txt`!

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @KlausD. ! My dockerfile and the req.txt are above now.